# Can True Seeing tell the difference between a statue and a foo creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters

A creature with the [foo template](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/foo-creature-cr-1/) has the ability called freeze

> A foo creature can hold itself so still it appears to be a statue. A foo creature that uses freeze can take 10 on its Stealth check to hide in plain sight as a stone statue. A foo creature can maintain this position for as long as it wishes.

[True Seeing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing/)

> You confer on the subject the ability to see all things as they actually are. The subject sees through normal and magical darkness, notices secret doors hidden by magic, sees the exact locations of creatures or objects under blur or displacement effects, sees invisible creatures or objects normally, sees through illusions, and sees the true form of polymorphed, changed, or transmuted things. Further, the subject can focus its vision to see into the Ethereal Plane (but not into extra-dimensional spaces). The range of true seeing conferred is 120 feet.
>
> True seeing, however, does not penetrate solid objects. It in no way confers X-ray vision or its equivalent. It does not negate concealment, including that caused by fog and the like. True seeing does not help the viewer see through mundane disguises, spot creatures who are simply hiding, or notice secret doors hidden by mundane means. In addition, the spell effects cannot be further enhanced with known magic, so one cannot use true seeing through a crystal ball or in conjunction with clairaudience/clairvoyance.

So the creature isnt hiding per-say but can someone under the effects of the spell tell the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, *True Seeing* won't be of any use against the *freeze* ability ...

The fluff text of *freeze* makes no mentions of the effect being magical in any way. Instead, it states

> A foo creature can hold itself so still it appears to be a statue.

This indicates that it's basically just able to stand very, very still for extended periods (it shouldn't matter if that is due to a different physiology or innate magic stuff).
If that's how your DM interpretes it as well, then *True Seeing* won't work, since it states:

> True seeing does not help the viewer see through mundane disguises, spot creatures who are simply hiding, [...]

Hence, *freeze* is just a "mundane" disguise, and therefore cannot be revealed with *True Seeing*.

---

### ... depending on how you visualize the ability / imagine it to work.

Depending on how your DM rules this, he might interpret the *freeze* ability as something that actually makes your skin appear differently. After all, it states:

> A foo creature can hold itself so still it appears to be a statue

Statues, however, are generally not made from flesh and bone, so for this to work (logically), your skin would have to look like stone.

In that case, *True Seeing* would indeed work, due to the phrase

> sees through illusions, and sees the true form of polymorphed, changed, or transmuted things

If your skin has a different appearance, it's either an illusion or one of the other mentioned effects.

Comment: Since the spell does not see through mundane disguises I felt that it would be unable to see past the freeze effect, but was unsure as it shows the true subject. Its not x-ray but it can see through a bear to the druid within?

Comment: @Fering In layman's terms, True Seeing just sees through, and the source of, magic.  He can't see through the bear, but he can see that the bear's supposed to be a druid, but isn't because of magic.  The question at the end of the day is, when a foo looks like a statue, is it because of magic, or just good camouflage?